# Should I write integration tests of common methods for every DAO?

Tags: java, integration-testing, dao

The code base that I work with has a common set of data-access methods in an abstract base class which is extended by many different entity-specific DAO classes.

As there are currently no tests covering any of this logic, I've started adding tests for a specific entity DAO which covers the common data-access methods as well as the custom methods in that DAO.

Writing tests to cover the exact same common methods for each other entity DAO seems like a waste of time and a maintenance nightmare, so I only have the one so far. On the other hand, having those tests for all entity DAOs may help us catch differences between our schema and entity mappings.

Is there any real benefit to having integration tests of common methods for every entity DAO?

Comment: Personally I prefer to have integration tests for business operations (that is to say calls into your service/business tier).  E.g. deleting a user might also require deleting a bunch of associated objects and may involve multiple DAO/persistence operations.  I find it much more useful to focus integration tests at that layer but just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, they will help you catch differences between your schema and entity mappings. It's really up to you to decide if the benefit of that is worth the cost of the development time and maintenance. E.g. Other business level tests may implicitly cover these cases already. The DAO tests seem more like unit tests anyways though.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to write test for all these methods, however here are somethings you should to take into consideration

- Time: It will take time to implement all these test. If for some reason you need to allocate development resources else where you should really take this into consideration.
- Maintenance: You need to maintain all these test, if you decide to write them.
- Redundancy: These method will behave similar in most cases and can be a waste of time to implement in the first place.